# Magento 2 theme override: changes not showing

Tags: theme, overrides, luma-theme, override-block, theme-overriding

I am new to Magento 2 and theming and I'm having trouble overriding a particular template. I am running in developer mode.

I have successfully installed my theme and applied it globally in the admin, using Luma as a parent.

```
<vender> = SampleStore
<theme> = sampletheme
```

I can tell it is working because I have added `_theme.less` to `<vender>/<theme>/web/css/source` and changed the background color of the body to red, which after a cache clear is reflected on the store in my browser.

**My issue is** when I try to override a template not just a style change my changes are ignored and the parent Luma template is served.

I am trying to add some text after QTY on the product page, just as a test.

I went into `vender/magento/` and copied **module-catalog** and all it's sub folders (as that is where the template for this particular change is) and paste them in my own vendor directory (not inside the `<theme>` directory, but right inside `<vender>`): `<vender>/**module-catalog**`

I deleted all the folders I didn't need, leaving me with `view/frontend/templates/*all files*`

Have I misunderstood where to place this `module-catalog` folder, have I missed out a step or something else? Why is my new template ignored and Luma being used?

[image]

I am using [this](https://jamersan.com/super-guide-theming-magento-2-part-2-3/) guide. Specifically this section:

> Template customization walkthrough
>
> To customize or override a template:
>
> 1. Locate the template which is associated with the page or block you
>      want to change, using template hints in developer tools. For example,
>      these would be located at:
>      `app/design/<vendor_name>/<module_name>/view/frontend/templates/`
> 2. Copy the template to your theme folder according to the template storing
>      convention.
> 3. Make the required changes.

Comment: Have you done `setup:static-content:deploy` and `cache:flush` command after all ?

Comment: @NikunjVadariya I am in developer mode so not required, thanks though. I will add that to my main post for clarity (I have cleared cache and deleted /generated)

Comment: I have added my answer for your fixe, Check and let me know if still any issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your path with below the structure.

> app/design/frontend/SampleStore/sampletheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

It will work.

Comment: This worked great, it is now using my template :) However I have a new issue, the style has gone missing on the page. Does this mean when a template is overridden, the css alone will not default back to Luma? I must also override the css?

Comment: @GoldenGonaz follow the magento guide: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking at but wasn't able to find an answer. I will take another look :)

Comment: Incase anyone else reads this with the style loss issue. The reason was I had created web/css/source/_theme.less to change the body background color. This was for some reason losing all the styles from the whole site. Once I removed this file, the styles reappeared globally. I will need to write new styles but I assume (I don't know for sure) that I will extended them instead.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to override below file :

> module-catalog/view/frontend/template/product/view/addtocart.phtml

This file can be overriden in theme by copying the file to below location :

> app/design/frontend/ThemeVendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml

**Note:** view folder shouldn't be there as we are defining area in starting(`app/design/frotnend`)